# Place order button does not work Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

My website works completely fine until few hours ago I received couple of messages that customers cannot click on the Place order button. I have one step checkout module installed since day one that my site launched and suddenly it stopped working.

I clicked on the inspect console and this error pops up.

[image]

Please help..

Comment: one-step-checkout module disable after check

Comment: I did check after disabling the one step checkout, normal checkout module works fine. However, after enabling it. It place order button does not work

Comment: what's name of one-step-checkout extensions??

Comment: Its One Step Checkout (3.7.1) by Magestore

Comment: you open the network tab and click place order button after check which file color is red and open red color file

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8EZfmyq There is no red file

Comment: what showing in log error ??